# Move element up against window scroll in a directive then apply fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using an angular directive and binding the scroll on the window element.  On scroll, I want to move the element against the direction of the scroll up.  Then, when `boundingRect` reaches 50, I want to apply the fixed positioning.  It's not working... What am I missing?

**Directive**

```
app.directive('liftToTop', ['$window', function($window){
  return {
    restrict: 'A', //attributes only
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      const w = angular.element($window),
        topClass = attrs.liftToTop,
        initialOffset = element.offset().top;

      //bind the the scroll event  
      w.bind('scroll', function(){
        console.log(this.pageYOffset);

        let currentTop = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top; //get current pos

        if(currentTop > 50) {
          //move element up/down against the scroll direction
          element.css('top', -1 * this.pageYOffset + 'px');
          element.removeClass(topClass);
        }

        //once current rect reaches 50, apply fixed
        if(currentTop === 50) {
          element.addClass(topClass);
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

**CSS**

```
.then-fixed-to-top-10 {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<h1 lift-to-top="then-fixed-to-top-10">{{hello}}</h1>
```

**Here's non-working Plnkr**

https://plnkr.co/edit/n4dQDzwK5T6e3TqWGlR3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the the main problem was the way you measured scroll value. Also, the last if statement had to be changed from `===` to `>`:

```
let currentTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //get current pos

if(currentTop < 50) {
    //move element up/down against the scroll direction
    element.css('top', -1 * this.pageYOffset + 'px');
    element.removeClass(topClass);
}

//once current rect reaches 50, apply fixed
if(currentTop > 50) {
    element.addClass(topClass);
}
```

To make the `h1` stick without jumping to the left just add `width:100%` to the class:

```
.then-fixed-to-top-10 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not quite.  I need the current position of the **element** relative to the client screen, not the distance of the scroll given by `scrollTop()`.  Subtle difference :).  When I scroll down, the element should advance up until it reaches 50px, then it should remain fixed.

Comment: But once it's fixed it will never unstick itself. You want that?

Comment: If I continue scrolling down, it should stick to the top.  If I scroll back up, past the point where it got stuck (50px), I can remove the class to `fixed` it, can't I?

Comment: But you were measuring by object's position. Once it's stuck it's position will never change to trigger your "unstuck" action.

Comment: See this plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/FXOaqFMcMhNk2kD4GN3j?p=preview  I'm close.  At least I got it to stick and unstick.

Comment: So what's missing now?

Comment: The 'hello world' transition is very abrupt, not smooth.  And the `fixed` position jumped to the left on my screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132511/discussion-between-serg-chernata-and-kyle).

Comment: Amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to divide the initial offset by two to meet halfway.  I also needed to set the moving div width to equal the parent div to prevent jumping.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('liftToTop', function($window){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            const w = angular.element($window),
                topClass = attrs.liftToTop,
                initialOffset = element.offset().top;

            w.bind('scroll', function(){
                let currentTop = w.scrollTop(); //get current pos

                if(currentTop < initialOffset / 2) {
                    //move element up/down against the scroll direction
                    element.css('top', -1 * this.pageYOffset + 'px');
                    element.removeClass(topClass);
                }

                //once current rect reaches 50, apply fixed
                if(currentTop > (initialOffset / 2)) {
                    element.addClass(topClass);
                    element.removeAttr('style');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed-to-top-10 {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 400px;
}
```